# why the AES result is different between Crypto and M2Crypto with Python?

Tags: python, encryption

i have two script in python , one is encrypt data using Crypto

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random


IV = 'c782dc4c098c66cb'
secrect_key = 'c286696d887c9aa0'
cipher = AES.new(secrect_key, AES.MODE_CFB, IV)
data = 'This is a 48-byte message (exactly 3 AES blocks)'
print repr(cipher.encrypt(data))
```

and the other using M2Crypto

```
import M2Crypto.EVP as EVP
import cStringIO

ENCRYPT_OP = 1
DECRYPT_OP = 0

def aes_encrypt(iv, secret_key, plain_text):
    cipher = EVP.Cipher(alg='aes_128_cfb', 
                        key=secret_key, 
                        iv=iv,
                        op=ENCRYPT_OP)

    input_buffer  = cStringIO.StringIO(plain_text)        
    cipher_data1 = cipher.update(input_buffer.read())
    cipher_data2 = cipher.final()
    input_buffer.close()

    output_buffer = cStringIO.StringIO()
    output_buffer.write(cipher_data1)
    output_buffer.write(cipher_data2)
    cipher_text = output_buffer.getvalue()    
    output_buffer.close()

    return cipher_text

IV = 'c782dc4c098c66cb' # 16 bytes
secrect_key = 'c286696d887c9aa0' # 16 bytes

data = 'This is a 48-byte message (exactly 3 AES blocks)'

cipher_text = aes_encrypt(IV, secrect_key, data)

print(repr(cipher_text))
```

i have pass the same argument to module, but i cannot get the same result, i don't know why.

and, is one of the result is vulnerability?

Comment: Do both really take hex-encoded strings as IVs and keys? That seems odd.